# Is a Java Microedition RMS tagged as modified when it is opened but no data change is made?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, rms

I want to know if opening an RMS record checks it as modified in javame.
For example

```
RecordStore rs;

//First RMS access 
rs.open("gamescores",true);
rs.addRecord(null,0,0);
rs.closeRecordStore;

//Second RMS access
rs = RecordStore.open("gamescores",true);
long timeStamp = rs.getLastModified();
rs.closeRecordStore();
```

would getLastModified() return the time of the first RMS access or of the second one.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see, and post the results here as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

A different method is intended to track modifications of records - [getVersion()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html#getVersion%28%29):

> Each time a record store is modified (by `addRecord`, `setRecord`, or `deleteRecord` methods) its version is incremented. This can be used by MIDlets to quickly tell if anything has been modified. The initial version number is implementation dependent. The increment is a positive integer greater than 0. The version number increases only when the RecordStore is updated. The increment value need not be constant and may vary with each update.

As for [getLastModified](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html#getLastModified%28%29) method, its specification doesn't allow to reliably tell the difference you're asking about in a portable way:

> Returns the last time the record store was modified, in the format used by System.currentTimeMillis().

Answer (score 0):

Up-till now i have never use this `getLastModified()` method so i google it and found and [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/BirthdayDatabase.htm). So yes the method returns the last modified time as in long format which you can easily convert into date.